# Unique Assets with same name in my possession

Tags: eldritch-horror, reference

When Encounter instructs me to gain new Unique Asset and I receive the same card that I have in my possession.

What happens? Do I get both of them or I should discard the card I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep both. There is no limit, according to [the FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/6d/33/6d33e762-f0e4-4f51-89b6-88e3354634cc/eh_errata__faq_2017-08-11.pdf):

> Q. Can an investigator have multiple copies of the same  Unique
>   Asset?
>   A. Yes. There is no limit to the number of Unique Assets an 
>   investigator can have.

[Source](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1542649/can-you-have-more-one-copy-unique-asset)